# Mismatch in Number/Types of Arguments

Tags: rust, lifetime

This

```rust
extern crate postgres;

use postgres::{Connection, SslMode};

struct User {
    reference: String,
    email: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String
}

static DB_URI: &'static str = "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/test";

fn main() {

    let conn = Connection::connect(DB_URI, &SslMode::None).unwrap();
    let trans = conn.transaction().unwrap();

    //...

}

fn insert_user<'a>(trans: &'a postgres::Transaction, user: &User) -> &'a postgres::Result {
    //...
}
```

is throwing an error

```
error: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0 [E0243]
fn insert_user<'a>(trans: &'a postgres::Transaction, user: &User) -> &'a postgres::Result {
                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What is missing here? I just want to return a result of an executed query.

**UPDATE** So I modified the function line like this:

```rust
fn insert_user(trans: &postgres::Transaction, user: &User) -> &postgres::Result<()> {
```

to trick the compiler into revealing the correct return type and it gave me this:

```
mismatched types:
 expected `core::result::Result<(), postgres::error::Error>`,
    found `core::result::Result<postgres::Rows<'_>, postgres::error::Error>`
```

however when I tried to match the return type like this:

```rust
fn insert_user(trans: &postgres::Transaction, user: &User) -> &postgres::Result<postgres::Rows<'_>, postgres::error::Error> {
```

it's now throwing a new error:

```
error: use of undeclared lifetime name `'_` [E0261]
fn insert_user(trans: &postgres::Transaction, user: &User) -> postgres::Result<postgres::Rows<'_>, postgres::error::Error> {
                                                                                              ^~
```

Comment: It's exactly what it says. You've given it the wrong number of type arguments. [`Result`](http://sfackler.github.io/rust-postgres/doc/v0.9.1/postgres/type.Result.html) takes the type for the returned valid value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://sfackler.github.io/rust-postgres/doc/v0.9.1/postgres/type.Result.html) for the crate `postgres`, we can see that the type `postgres::Result` is generic over one type argument:

```
type Result<T> = Result<T, Error>;
```

Normally you would have two options:

1. Specify the type yourself if you know what it is: `postgres::Result<MyType>`
2. Let the compiler infer it for you (if it has enough information elsewhere): `postgres::Result<_>`

However in a return type (what comes after the `->`) type inference is not triggered, so only option 1. is available.

(Hint: you still have one trick up your sleeve to find out the desired type. You can try specifying the unit type: `... -> postgres::Result<()>` and check if the compiler complains with an error such as "expected `MyType`, found `()`". This means you want to specify `... -> postgres::Result<MyType>`.)

Comment: Thanks for the trick advice, made some progress with it, but the compiler is still complaining, I'm sure there's a reason.

Comment: I would advise to reinstate the lifetime `'a` you had, and use it instead of `'_`, since the compiler is not inferring it.

Comment: @Caballero indeed you went just one step too far in copying the error message, because `'_` is an anonymous lifetime and it's discouraged that you name a lifetime `'_`. Usually they're called `'a` or `'b`. Seeing [your second question in a row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784279/rust-borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough), I suggest that maybe you want to pause writing code for a little while and get to know the language with the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book) (specifically here, the [lifetimes section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html)).

Comment: @mdup that section doesn't help with my particular situation, all the examples are very simple.

Answer (score 2):

`Result` is defined as `postgres::Result<T>` (we say it is *generic over T*). Depending on the innards of the insert_user function, it could be `Result<bool>`, `Result<u64>`, `Result<()>` or something else entierly.

For example, the `execute` method on `Transaction` returns a `Result<u64>`, so that is a likely variant.