# Borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: rust

This is my code

```rust
extern crate postgres;

use postgres::{Connection, SslMode};

struct User {
    reference: String,
    email: String
}

static DB_URI: &'static str = "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/test";

fn main() {

    let conn = Connection::connect(DB_URI, &SslMode::None).unwrap();
    let trans = conn.transaction().unwrap();

    let user = User {
        reference: "123abc".to_string(),
        email: "test@test.com".to_string()
    };

    let result = insert_user(&trans, &user);

    trans.set_commit();
    trans.finish();

}

fn insert_user<'_>(trans: &postgres::Transaction<'_>, user: &User) -> postgres::Result<postgres::rows::Rows<'_>> {
    let query = "INSERT INTO usr (reference, email) VALUES ($1, $2)";
    trans.prepare(query).unwrap().query(&[&user.reference, &user.email])
}
```

It's producing an error:

```
src/main.rs:31:2: 31:31 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
src/main.rs:31  trans.prepare(query).unwrap().query(&[&user.reference, &user.email])
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:29:114: 32:2 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime '_ as defined on the block at 29:113...
src/main.rs:29 fn insert_user<'_>(trans: &postgres::Transaction<'_>, user: &User) -> postgres::Result<postgres::rows::Rows<'_>> {
src/main.rs:30  let query = "INSERT INTO usr (reference, email) VALUES ($1, $2)";
src/main.rs:31  trans.prepare(query).unwrap().query(&[&user.reference, &user.email])
src/main.rs:32 }
src/main.rs:29:114: 32:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 29:113
src/main.rs:29 fn insert_user<'_>(trans: &postgres::Transaction<'_>, user: &User) -> postgres::Result<postgres::rows::Rows<'_>> {
src/main.rs:30  let query = "INSERT INTO usr (reference, email) VALUES ($1, $2)";
src/main.rs:31  trans.prepare(query).unwrap().query(&[&user.reference, &user.email])
src/main.rs:32 }
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `test`.
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: There are many questions here with the same error. Please show that you have done the required legwork and explain how this is different than existing questions.

Comment: I asked a concise Question for this common rust error `error[E0716]` [error E0716: temporary value dropped while borrowed (rust)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626083/error-e0716-temporary-value-dropped-while-borrowed-rust). It links back to this Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```rust
fn insert_user<'a>(trans: &postgres::Transaction<'a>, user: &User) -> postgres::Result<postgres::rows::Rows<'a>> {
```

(I've changed the lifetime parameter name to some usual one)

Here you are stating that lifetime in `Rows` parameter in the result should be the same as the lifetime in `Transaction` parameter (which is essentially a lifetime of `Connection` object). However, lifetime parameter of `Rows` equals to the lifetime of a `Statement`, and `Statement` value (created by the call of `prepare()` method) is a local variable, so it is strictly smaller than required (lifetimes of local variables are always smaller than lifetimes specified in parameters).

This error is legitimate - Rust prevented an actual logic mistake here. `Rows` iterator requires a `Statement` to load its data, but in this case `Statement` is destroyed while `Rows` is still alive.

What you need to do is to collect the data from `Rows` to some container (e.g. `Vec`) and return it. However, `insert_user()` seems to be a query which does not return anything from the database. For such queries you should use [`execute()`](http://sfackler.github.io/rust-postgres/doc/v0.9.1/postgres/struct.Statement.html#method.execute) method on `Statement`, and your function should look like this:

```rust
fn insert_user(trans: &postgres::Transaction, user: &User) -> postgres::Result<u64> {
    let query = "INSERT INTO usr (reference, email) VALUES ($1, $2)";
    trans.prepare(query).unwrap().execute(&[&user.reference, &user.email])
}
```